# Embedding PHP in HTML

Tags: php, html

I was curious to see if the following:

```
<td><?=JText::_('_EMAIL')?></td>
```

is equivalent to:

```
<td><?php echo JText::_('_EMAIL')?></td>
```

I know it's possible to do:

```
<td class=<?=$somestring;?>> <!-- markup --> </td>
```

but, in the case of there being an expression tag which is not necessarily linking up with an attribute, I wasn't sure if it would produce the same effect.

Is this true?

Comment: I would, but I'm at a point where I'm writing so much code that I'm not ready to test...and I'm working with joomla, which makes it harder to test.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you building a stand-alone reduced test case.

Comment: Don't have the time - I'm on a deadline. Speaking of, I should probably get off here -_-; thank you all for the info.

Comment: I think pasting this into a simple test file would have been a lot faster then formulating a SO question and responding to annoying comments. ;-P

Comment: But, it IS a useful question. I'm sure there are plenty of php coders who have been curious about it. Isn't that what SO is all about? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?php` and `?>` just look like SGML/XML processing instructions. As far as PHP is concerned, it is looking for them in text, not markup. It doesn't matter where you put them.

Answer (score 3):

PHP tags don't care where they start or end. PHP does not evaluate anything outside of `<?php ?>` tags, so it doesn't matter where they occur. Yes, all three snippets will output content. `<?=` is simply the shorthand version of `<?php echo`, and BTW, it's discouraged because "[short open tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)" can be disabled, whereas `<?php` always works.

Comment: A small heads up: `<?=` [will be always available](http://www.php.net/releases/NEWS_5_4_0_alpha1.txt) in PHP >= 5.4 even if short open tags are not. In a year or so this could start having practical impact.

Comment: @deceze Yes, but imo it's quite cleaner to implement them via shorthand. That is, in cases such as this. Otherwise I use the normal tags.